# DNAT redirecting to specifc port is not working

Tags: ssh, iptables, port-forwarding, nat

I want to redirect ssh by port using DNAT, and i do try to ssh it through the `command > username@IP_ADDRESS:10003`, and I got this message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname IP_ADDRESS:10003: Name or service not known
```

My configuration looks fine to me, does it needs any change?

Those rules I used:

```
#default policy
iptables --policy INPUT DROP
iptables --policy OUTPUT DROP
iptables --policy FORWARD DROP
#connection states
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $EXTERNAL_ETH -p tcp  --sport $OTHER_PORTS --dport 10003 -d $PUBLIC_IP -j DNAT --to-destination $SERVER2:22
iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTERNAL_ETH -o $INTERNAL_ETH -p tcp --sport $OTHER_PORTS --dport 22 -d $SERVER2 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

and that is how it looks in the output

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
4        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            $1111.1111.11.1       tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:10003 to:10.0.0.3:22

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
10       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.3             tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:22 state NEW
```

Comment: I do not understand `$1111.1111.11.1`. You do not appear to have a `SNAT` or `MASQUERADE` POSTROUTING return path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this command:

```
ssh username@IP_ADDRESS -p 10003
```